# is there any function to Lazy Load images on Shiny App in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have this set of arround 15000 images that I show on my shiny app but whenever I load this up the app takes 2 minutes just to load all the images on desktop also it take lot of memory on device. is there any way to lazy load this app?? I already tried to make my HTML code with loading="lazy" but still it is taking 2 minutes to load the view.

```
ui <- navbarPage("[GOWNDY]",#theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
                 useShinyjs(),             
                 tabPanel("Regional",
                          titlePanel("Regional Vids"),
                          textOutput("regvideost") %>% 
                            tagAppendAttributes(class = 'date'),
                          #actionButton("vidbtn", "Refresh"),
                          #actionButton("test", "Test"),
                          #selectInput("sortinput", "Sort:",c("Descending" = "desc","Ascending" = "asc")),
                          hr(),
                          uiOutput("regvids"),
                          
                 ),                 
                 
                 
          
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  
  
  output$regvids <- renderUI({
    regvideos <- readRDS(file ="regvideos.Rda")
    lapply(1:length(regvideos), function(i) {
      HTML(paste0('<a href="',regvideos[[i]]$url,'"><img loading="lazy" src="',
                  'https://img.youtube.com/vi/',regvideos[[i]]$id,'/hqdefault.jpg',
                  '" alt="',regvideos[[i]]$id,'" style="width:100%;"></a>','<h3>',
                  "Views: ",as.integer(regvideos[[i]][["views_count"]])," Likes: ",
                  as.integer(regvideos[[i]][["statistics"]][["likeCount"]])," VPH : ",
                  as.integer(regvideos[[i]]$vph),'</h3>','<h2>',regvideos[[i]]$title,'</h2>',
                  '<hr style="width:100%;height:10px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">'))
    })
  })   
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There are some [jQuery plugins](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage) for lazy loading. But what you want to do is not clear.

Comment: I am presenting Youtube Thumbnails, a bunch ol them so I am looping the function and creating a giant HTML Document and rendering using renderUI and presenting it through uiOutput("regvids")